# How to do addition operations intuitively with datetime in AutoHotKey?

Tags: datetime, variables, addition, autohotkey, readability

I find that there are two ways to calculate the date in AutoHotKey:

- Use [EnvAdd](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/EnvAdd.htm), which is synonymous with `var += value`
- Convert the date to the YYYYMMDDHH24MISS format, and calculate it as if it's a regular number, then convert back to date format

It seems that using EnvAdd is better, because it has a parameter to determine the time unit. (Using the second method may lead to unaccepted value, such as days 62 or month 20.) But since EnvAdd only changes the current value of the input variable, not assign the result to another variable, so if I want to have keep the original one, I have to do this:

```
a:=b
a+=10
```

This is counter-intuitive, because the original value is stored in a new variable, while it's more natural to expect the original value is stored in the old variable.

Is there a way to keep it more natural to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused. I should have used:

```
b := a
b += 10, months
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
a:=b+10
```

Comment: oh I find out where I'm stuck. I want to calculate dates and times, and you can't calculate directly on the YYYYMMDDHH24MISS format, since there would be unaccepted value. You have to do this via EnvAdd, because it has a parameter to determine the time unit. I have updated the question, can you check it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Please specify what exactly you are trying to do including expected input and output.

Comment: I edit it again. Can you check it? (EnvAdd only changes the current value of the input variable, not assign the result to another variable. This is counter-intuitive, because the original value is stored in a new variable, while it's more natural to expect the original value is stored in the old variable.)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you that way. You don't show example input, you don't show example output, you keep talking about EnvAdd and in your example code you suddenly use things like `a+=10`.